# mediaDevices API opens the wrong camera, is there a way to set which camera you want to use?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am using `.getUserMedia()` to get the video source for my web app.

Everything works, however on my Samsung s10+ it always opens the ultrawide lens, I want to open the "default rear camera lens", but how can I even know which camera is the default?

I don't understand this, because every other app instagram, snapchat, tiktok seems to always open the "default" camera, how do they recognise it, since most phones come with 3+ rear cameras?

Is the native development different or can this be achieved in the web app as well?

I'm using Quagga Js library for barcode reading functionality btw.

```
 Quagga.init(
      {
        inputStream: {
          name: "Live",
          type: "LiveStream",
          target: ".scannerArea", // Or '#yourElement' (optional),
          constraints: {
            facingMode: "environment",
          },
        },
        decoder: {
          readers: ["code_128_reader", "upc_reader", "ean_reader"],
        },
      },
      function (err) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          return;
        }
        console.log("Initialization finished. Ready to start");
        Quagga.start();
      }
    );
    Quagga.onDetected((result) => {
      let last_code = result.codeResult.code;
      alert(last_code);
      Quagga.stop();
    });
```

Comment: you might want to add a code snippet of what you have already tried

Comment: Check [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/front-and-rear-camera-access-with-javascripts-getusermedia) out!

Comment: I added the code, I am using Quagga Js library